# Parsing the Rightmove api

Tags: api

I have a client who uploads his properties into 3rd party software created by a company called 'estates it', who then send that file, as a .blm to rightmove who process it.

This client wants us to take that .blm file and output the data into a new designed site we are doing. Does anyone know of methods or experience in doing this or working with .blm files? Which is a static file as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suppose this will be of help to you anymore, but if anyone else is looking for ways to handle the rightmove BLM file:

You can find several solutions implemented [here](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=rightmove&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)
Using this [repo](https://github.com/stilliard/blmreader), for example, you can just:

```
$blm = new \BLM\Reader(dirname(__FILE__)  . '/test.blm')
var_dump($blm->toArray());
```

Most solutions I've seen are implemented in PHP though, and seem to be pretty old.

In the case the website is a wordpress, there seem to be a couple puglins for this too ([example](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-property-blm-export-add-on/)).

I'm not too sure Rightmove still outputs a BLM on the [latest version of its api](http://www.rightmove.co.uk/adf.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple process. We are currently working the other way. ie our system manages an estate agents property listings and sends them to rightmove for listing.

The rightmove API definition can be found at [www.rightmove.co.uk/adf.html](http://www.rightmove.co.uk/adf.html)

The file comprises a definition and data file within each blm, this should make it quite straight forward to manage